# bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$' trying to insert document with pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to insert document to the collection from json file it says `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$'`
How can I solve it?

example of document:

`[{"name": "Company", "_id": {"$oid": "1234as123541gsdg"}, "info": {"email": "test@gmail.com"}}]`

Comment: Could you give example document? It seems that you have value of the document id starting with "$"

Comment: You're most likely going to need to escape that `$`.
A simple way is: `import re; re.escape({your variable here})`

Comment: I have updated the question body with example of document

Comment: What is wrong with `"_id":  "1234as123541gsdg"`?

Comment: I get it when I dump the collection to json file

Answer (score 11):

Represent ObjectIds in Python with the `bson.ObjectId` class:

```
from bson import ObjectId

_id = ObjectId("5899e0aca600741755433908")
```

So for a complete example:

```
from bson import ObjectId

collection.insert(
    {"name": "Company", "_id": ObjectId("5899e0aca600741755433908"),
     "info": {"email": "test@gmail.com"}})
```

In order to load MongoDB Extended JSON data, use PyMongo's [`json_util.loads`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html#bson.json_util.loads):

```
from bson.json_util import loads

json_str = '[{"name": "Company", "_id": {"$oid": "5899e0aca600741755433908"}, "info": {"email": "test@gmail.com"}}]'

data = loads(json_str)
print(data)

for doc in data:
    collection.insert(doc)
```

"loads()" converts from the Extended JSON syntax with "$oid" to an actual ObjectId instance.

Comment: You're welcome! Is there anything else I should add to my answer, or will you mark it as correct?

Comment: Anyone knows if there is something similar for Ruby?

Comment: Just wanted to spell it out that you can get the json_str from the json file with file.read(). open("filepath", "r") as f:
    json_str = f.read()

Comment: Is there a similar library for node?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing all white space in the files (\n, spaces outside string quotes). It may work like miracle

Comment: Please remember that: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." [How-do-I-write-a-good-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)