# Unable to insert Jsonfile into mongodb using python (pymongo) (Error: bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$')

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I have a json file that needs to be inserted into MongoDB using python. In my json file I have the following snippet:
filename: roles

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "1a2e34r6hyhujujikijk"
  },
  "sequence": 255559,
  "name": "cruisemethods",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-03-31T02:37:21.716Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2020-08-27T14:04:59.333Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}]%
```

When I try to insert the above json(which is in a file), it throws an error for both objectid and date:
`bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$'`

My code:

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('URL')
Dictionarysample = {'DBname':'collectionname'};
def func(db_name, col_name):
    dbid = getattr(client,db_name)
    collection = getattr(dbid,col_name)
    with open('Filepath') as file:
        file_data = json.load(file)
        if isinstance(file_data, list):
              collection.insert_many(file_data)
        else:
              collection.insert_one(file_data)
for key in Dictionarysample:
    func(key,Dictionarysample[key])
```

Versions

```
python: Python 3.8.2
pymongo: pymongo 3.11.3
MongodAtlas: Version 4.4.3
```

Tried almost all the existing stackoverflow suggestions
[bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$' trying to insert document with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089045/bson-errors-invaliddocument-key-oid-must-not-start-with-trying-to-insert), but it still didn't work.

Can somebody help me on this?

[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n29aK.png)

Comment: The only reason i can think why it's not working is you are using `json.load(file)` which is from the `Json` package instead of `bson.json_util` as suggested in the post you have tagged.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB uses an [extended JSON format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-extended-json-v2) in order to represent data types such as [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.ObjectId) that are not supported by standard JSON.

The object `{ "$oid": "1a2e34r6hyhujujikijk" }` (that's not a valid ObjectID by the way) should be converted to an [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#objectid) prior to submitting to the mongod node.

MongoDB also has additional [field name restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) such as fields may not start with a dollar sign.

The standard JSON parser that you are using is not aware of the MongoDB extensions or restrictions.

You might consider [bson.json_util](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html#module-bson.json_util) from pymongo to handle these automatically.

Comment: I tried using  bson.json_util i am getting below error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongo.py", line 27, in <module>
    func(key,Dictionarysample[key])
  File "mongo.py", line 11, in func
    file_data = bson.json_util.loads(file)
NameError: name 'bson' is not defined
i have bson installed already, and i followed these steps as well
pip uninstall bson
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo.        asper stackoverflow results

Comment: did you import `bson` first?