# Successfully insert multiple document into MongoDB [Python]

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have the following piece of code in python:

```
def pushHashtagPosts(hashtagPosts):
    from bson.json_util import loads
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(mongoUri)
    mydb = myclient["myDB"]
    mycol = mydb["hashtags"]
    data = loads(hashtagPosts)
    posts = mycol.insert_many(data)
```

Whereas, the content of hashtagPosts looks something like this:

```
hashtagPosts = [{'hashtag': '###!', 'PostHashHex': '13fc9904028fb62490a3b5dc2111689376e52a06dc636c3322cfa16e33a41398', 'post': {'_id': {'$oid': '608f8eb73718c7977f9c0a43'}, 'PostHashHex': '13fc9904028fb62490a3b5dc2111689376e52a06dc636c3322cfa16e33a41398', 'PosterPublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv', 'ParentStakeID': '', 'Body': 'Need hashtags ####! Or else it’s a bit difficult to create personal brand and niche on this platform. \n\nDevs are u listening?', 'ImageURLs': [], 'RecloutedPostEntryResponse': None, 'CreatorBasisPoints': 0, 'StakeMultipleBasisPoints': 12500, 'TimestampNanos': 1.6177643730879583e+18, 'IsHidden': False, 'ConfirmationBlockHeight': 13248, 'InMempool': False, 'StakeEntry': {'TotalPostStake': 0, 'StakeList': []}, 'StakeEntryStats': {'TotalStakeNanos': 0, 'TotalStakeOwedNanos': 0, 'TotalCreatorEarningsNanos': 0, 'TotalFeesBurnedNanos': 0, 'TotalPostStakeNanos': 0}, 'ProfileEntryResponse': None, 'Comments': None, 'LikeCount': 5, 'PostEntryReaderState': None, 'InGlobalFeed': False, 'IsPinned': False, 'PostExtraData': {}, 'CommentCount': 2, 'RecloutCount': 0, 'ParentPosts': None, 'PublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv', 'Username': ''}}, 
{'hashtag': 'investementstrategy', 'PostHashHex': '92f2d08ac8f2b47fe5868b748c7f472e13ad12c284bb0e327cf317b4c2514f83', 'post': {'_id': {'$oid': '608f8eb73718c7977f9c0a3f'}, 'PostHashHex': '92f2d08ac8f2b47fe5868b748c7f472e13ad12c284bb0e327cf317b4c2514f83', 'PosterPublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv', 'ParentStakeID': '', 'Body': 'Don’t say that you are going to buy ur own coin to have a steady growth of ur coin \U0001fa99. That doesn’t show the strength of ur investment nor the coin. Strength lies in others believing in ur talent, creativity and passion enough to invest in U. \n#InvestementStrategy', 'ImageURLs': [], 'RecloutedPostEntryResponse': None, 'CreatorBasisPoints': 0, 'StakeMultipleBasisPoints': 12500, 'TimestampNanos': 1.6178065064906166e+18, 'IsHidden': False, 'ConfirmationBlockHeight': 13397, 'InMempool': False, 'StakeEntry': {'TotalPostStake': 0, 'StakeList': []}, 'StakeEntryStats': {'TotalStakeNanos': 0, 'TotalStakeOwedNanos': 0, 'TotalCreatorEarningsNanos': 0, 'TotalFeesBurnedNanos': 0, 'TotalPostStakeNanos': 0}, 'ProfileEntryResponse': None, 'Comments': None, 'LikeCount': 2, 'PostEntryReaderState': None, 'InGlobalFeed': False, 'IsPinned': False, 'PostExtraData': {}, 'CommentCount': 1, 'RecloutCount': 0, 'ParentPosts': None, 'PublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv', 'Username': ''}}, 
{'hashtag': 'productivity', 'PostHashHex': 'c8fabd96f5d624d06ec8d23e90de19cf07ad4b6696dac321fda815c3000fbf1b', 'post': {'_id': {'$oid': '608f8eb73718c7977f9c0a3d'}, 'PostHashHex': 'c8fabd96f5d624d06ec8d23e90de19cf07ad4b6696dac321fda815c3000fbf1b', 'PosterPublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv', 'ParentStakeID': '', 'Body': 'What is the most productive thing u have done in last 24 hours apart from Bitclout???\n\n\U0001f9d0 #productivity', 'ImageURLs': [], 'RecloutedPostEntryResponse': None, 'CreatorBasisPoints': 0, 'StakeMultipleBasisPoints': 12500, 'TimestampNanos': 1.6178362054980055e+18, 'IsHidden': False, 'ConfirmationBlockHeight': 13487, 'InMempool': False, 'StakeEntry': {'TotalPostStake': 0, 'StakeList': []}, 'StakeEntryStats': {'TotalStakeNanos': 0, 'TotalStakeOwedNanos': 0, 'TotalCreatorEarningsNanos': 0, 'TotalFeesBurnedNanos': 0, 'TotalPostStakeNanos': 0}, 'ProfileEntryResponse': None, 'Comments': None, 'LikeCount': 30, 'PostEntryReaderState': None, 'InGlobalFeed': True, 'IsPinned': False, 'PostExtraData': {}, 'CommentCount': 59, 'RecloutCount': 0, 'ParentPosts': None, 'PublicKeyBase58Check': 'BC1YLhKJZZcPB2WbZSSekFF19UshsmmPoEjtEqrYakzusLmL25xxAJv', 'Username': ''}}]
```

When I try to insert this data as insert_many() into mongodb I get the following error:

> File "test.py", line X, in pushHashtagPosts
> data = loads(hashtagPosts) TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'

However, I have inserted the line 'data = loads(hashtagPosts)' based on the solution at [bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$' trying to insert document with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42089045/4190159) because without the 'data = loads(hashtagPosts)' I was getting the following error:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$oid' must not start with '$'

How to resolve this and successfully insert many documents in the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `hashtagPosts` is a list but `loads` expects to work on a string.

So working backwards, the question becomes how did you construct `hashtagPosts` in the first place? As it contains `$oid` values, it looks like an output from `dumps`; but an output from `dumps` is a string. not a list. So how did it become a list?

If you are creating it manually, then just set it using `ObjectId`, e.g.

```
from bson import ObjectId
item = {'_id': ObjectId('608f8eb73718c7977f9c0a43')}
```

and then you won't need to use `loads`.